# MathJax isn't loaded into the comments; browser Firefox

Tags: discussion, mathjax, comment, firefox

As the title says MathJax isn't loaded into the comments in Firefox (but works fine for the answers!). Does someone else has the same problem? How to fix it? (Everything works fine in Chrome.)
This issue occurred yesterday.

Comment: I'm having the very same problem: not only MathJax, but if I try to flag a comment, the flagging menu does not show. The same happens on every other SE community that I belong to, so it seems to be a SE-related issue, not a MSE one. Moderators, could you please forward this to the SE team?

Comment: I observe the same. The formula source text is loaded, then removed, but not replaced with the rendered formula. Additionally, frequently but not always the comment is cut where the first formula would start.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: 52.6.0 (32-bit) as in the answer. Looking at the selection source of a comment, everything is "rendered" to MathML, just not shown.

Comment: Should work again now.

Comment: @balpha Yes, indeed.

Comment: Testing: $\mu(n) = \delta_{\Omega(n)}^{\omega(n)}$...

Comment: For what it's worth, I've noticed this but haven't always noticed if it's limited to the comments or not.

Answer (score 5):

[Answer copied from [Comments with MathJax not rendered on Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306506/comments-with-mathjax-not-rendered-on-firefox-esr). ]

As noted in the comments to the post [Date/time on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/date-time-on-comments), there are two workarounds for now for Firefox ESR 52.6.0.

- Click on "show xx more comments" (if this is present).
- Otherwise, open and close the Web Developer Inspector panel (Cntrl+Shift+C).

Hopefully, these will be needed only temporarily.

Comment: **Update:** The developer says he/she hopes to have a quick patch ready tomorrow, [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/comment-timestamp-is-not-showing-in-firefox-esr#comment996487_306503).

Comment: **Update:** This has now been fixed; see [Comment timestamp is not showing in Firefox ESR](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503). Thank you very much, [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha).